# How to disable the cart function by Magento administration panel?

Tags: cart, administration, admin-panel

How to disable the cart function by Magento administration panel?
Shortcuts to get it up

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly it is that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is an ecommerce system, it is not designed to disable core functionality.

I suggest to remove all add to cart buttons from the templates (`addto.phtml` editing might be enough) and implement an observer which avoids calling `checkout/cart/index`